# Accessing multiple instances through a function of a class

Tags: python, class

How to access multiple instances at same time through a function in a class?

I have learnt about parameters like `other`, but what if I have 3 objects and I need to access them all in the same function at the same time, how can I do that?

So here is the code I'm trying to correct:

```
class Vector2D:

    def __init__(self, x, y):

        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __add__(self, other, other_1):

        return Vector2D(self.x + other.x + other_1.x, self.y + other.y)

first = Vector2D(5, 7)
second = Vector2D(3, 9)
third = Vector2D(1, 1)
result = first + second + third

print(result.x)
print(result.y)}
```

It's showing the following error:

```
TypeError: __add__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'other_1'
```

How can I correct it?

Comment: Can't you just pass the objects as arguments?

Comment: What do you mean by "access them all … at a same time"?

Comment: ```self``` and ```other``` are not a keyword in python, you can use any word, they're just commonly used by pythoners. So use other_1, other_2 etc... to access multiple instances.

Comment: Guys its a clear question. He is asking a way to deal with more than one instances of a class in the definition of a method. He knows one has to use ```other``` to deal with another instance, now what if he wants to deal with multiple instances. I believe that's his question.

Comment: @Babydesta So pass each instance as an argument to the function?

Comment: @Baby `def foo(self, other, yet_another): ...`…!? This would be so obvious an answer that it's unclear where exactly the question is.

Comment: @GoodDeeds, the question is closed as not clear

Comment: @deceze, most text books teach you to use ```other```, ```cls``` and ```self``` as if they are a keyword. I think that's his confusion.  Also I searched stackoverflow and there is no question related to this one. so its I'm sure it will be asked again. its better to close it as already-answered  if you can find another similar question

Comment: @Baby *Maybe!?* Your guess is as good as mine. You know what would help? If OP clarified their question to let us know where exactly the confusion is…!

Comment: @deceze The OP has edited the question.

Comment: So earlier my doubt was wehther it is keyword or not now, I tried to edit the code its showing error. what should i do??

Comment: Since the question is closed I'll answer you here. instead of using ```__add__``` use ```add```, then ```result = first.add(second,third)```. That should work. Note that addition is a binary operation so ```a+b+c``` can not work in your case. Python is only dealing with ```a``` and ```b```, since its binary operation. that explains the error --  ```third``` is not being considered.

Comment: oh, let me try it

Comment: so if I want to use __add__() here then ???

Comment: To use `__add__()` just make it `return Vector2D(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)` — it can only deal with one "**other**" at a time, Python will call it twice as it evaluates the expression `first + second + third`. If you want to add exactly three (or more) at a time, then you'll need to write your own method that does it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `other_1` parameter:

```
>>> class Vector2D:
...     def __init__(self, x, y):
...         self.x = x
...         self.y = y
...     def __add__(self, other):
...         return Vector2D(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)
... 
>>> first = Vector2D(5, 7)
>>> second = Vector2D(3, 9)
>>> third = Vector2D(1, 1)
>>> result = first + second + third
>>> 
>>> print(result.x)
9
>>> print(result.y)
17
```

The idea is that `first + second + third` is equivalent to `(first + second) + third`.  Python only adds two things together at a time.